# CUDA application .exe has stopped working;error

Tags: cuda, nvidia

Am new to cuda. The above code is a cuda program am working on. when executing the for loop it shows that the lat.exe has stopped working. But when i decrease the for loop from 5000 to 1000 it works perfectly fine. How do i make it work with 5000 because that's the number i will be working with.

int main()
{

```
int *a, *b, *c;
int *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;


a = (int *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
b = (int *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
c = (int *)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));

cudaMalloc( &d_a, SIZE*sizeof(int));
cudaMalloc( &d_b, SIZE*sizeof(int));
cudaMalloc( &d_c, SIZE*sizeof(int));


for( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
{
    a[i] =i;
    b[i] =i;
    c[i] =0;
}

cudaMemcpy( d_a, a, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
cudaMemcpy( d_b, b, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
cudaMemcpy( d_c, c, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );


InitialAdd<<< 3 , SIZE >>>( d_a, d_b, d_c, SIZE);

cudaMemcpy( c, d_c, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

for( int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    printf("c[%d] = %d\n", i, c[i]);

free(a);
free(b);
free(c);

cudaFree(d_a);
cudaFree(d_b);
cudaFree(d_c);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: provides your code where d_b, d_c, d_a and c is allocated

Comment: Of course, `SIZE>=5000`, isn't it?

Comment: @user3018144 have edited it with the code you requested.

Comment: @JackOLantern. Yeah you are right missed that. Is working now. Thanks

Comment: You can not create block with 5000 threads ?!

Comment: I agree with user3018144.  Although SIZE>5000 will probably cause the observed problem ("application has stopped working") to go away, the code is still broken at that point.  If you're having trouble with CUDA code, you should be using [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api

Comment: @RobertCrovella user3018144 has provided an answer explaining that, but unfortunately he has deleted it.

Comment: @user3018144 Could you please repost your answer?

Answer (score 3):

you can not create block with 5000 threads. that's your problem. That's why your code is working with size = 1000 and not working with size = 5000. Block is up to 1024 threads (generally).